# Extended Events for Enable Disable Trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sql-server-2017, extended-events

We have a table that has a trigger defined on it
Sometimes, some application runs `disable trigger` command, then does something, then runs `enable trigger` to enable it back

Scanning the GIT, developers said they do not see this code (`disable trigger tr_TriggerName`) anywhere in repositories
My goal is to capture which app does that and when

Is there a corresponding event in Extended Events that can help me capture these events, along with information:

- which login that runs it
- whole batch of SQL, as it runs more than just disable / enable trigger in a batch

I've tried to search for "enable","trigger","ddl" within events library, but did not find anything, unless I am missing something

If there is better way to do it (not Extended Events), let me know

**update**: ChatGPT suggested using "ddl_command_start" event, but I can't find it in events library, probably it exists in SQL 2019 but not in SQL 2017

**update 2**: tried to use `object_altered` event as below answer suggested, scripted code is below:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Trigger_Enable_Disable] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.object_altered(
ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_server_principal_name,sqlserver.sql_text)
WHERE ([database_name]=N'MyDatabase' AND [object_name]=N'MyTrigger'))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'X:\ExtendedEvents\Trigger_Enable_Disable.xel',max_file_size=(102400))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
```

But it does not capture data when I manually disable enable that trigger

Answer (score 3):

When I create this Extended Event, it will grab the changes of the trigger:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [TestObjectChanges] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.object_altered(SET collect_database_name=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username))
```

[image]

Comment: tried this event "object_altered", but it did not work for me. Updated the question.

Comment: Remove the object trigger name. The alter is on the table.

Comment: So instead of MYTrigger, use MyTable

Comment: alright, I will try that and let you know

Comment: It should work as you see my printscreens 

Comment: I know :) thanks for giving me the direction. Upvoted. Got stuffed with work, I'll play with this more next week and get back to you here on my results

Comment: Great, happy to help. Let me know!